# Aptana, github & remote (sftp) files

Tags: php, git, github, aptana

currently I use Aptana to work directly with remote PHP files, which are stored on sftp server (the final, working version of the system). I'm thinking about switching to any version control system. As far as now I found git the most interesting. But the question is: how can I make aptana work with git repository (e.g. github) and after producing final version, synchronize it with sftp server? If I would like to move back to any previous version how can I do it, to make the previous version appear on sftp?

Thanks for any advices.